# newcommand for a 2x1 matrix

Tags: math-mode, macros, matrices

I want the following code to be a new command with two parameters (x and y):

```
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{bmatrix}
```

how can I do that?

Comment: Are you doing `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: yes i am using this package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\newcommand\ctwo[2]{%
\begin{bmatrix}
 #1\\
#2 
\end{bmatrix}}
```

then

```
\[
\ctwo{1}{2} + \ctwo{3}{4} = \ctwo{4}{6}
\]
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, although I have to wrap each \ctwo{x}{y} command in $$'s. Also why is there a "%" in the macro, doesnt that indicate a comment line?

Comment: @Coffeman use `\[` as I showed not `$$` and as shown here you should not have to wrap each `\ctwo` in math unless that is the entire expression. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to/69854#69854  for `%` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines-why-is-my-macro-creat

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help and information!